# How to convert HttpURL Connection request with to Volly request ??

Tags: android, android-volley, httpurlconnection

Here is my HttpURLConnection Request which is working fine.
I am sending json String with request
Now I have to convert this request to volley

```
  String jsonStr =    {"email":"test@gmail.com","full_name":"vghjj",
                   "locations":[],"mobile_no":"XXXXXXXXX",
                   "super_sectors":    [],"unique_device_id":"XXXXXXX","utm_params":"No Utm Params"}"


try {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = getHttpConnection(jsonStr, url, oauth, REQUEST_TYPE.POST.getType());

        if (urlConnection != null) {
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                result = convertInputStreamToString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            } 
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    } 

private static HttpURLConnection getHttpConnection(String jsonStr , String strUrl, Oauth oauth, String type) {
    URL url = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try {
        url = new URL(strUrl);
        /* */
        if (GlobalVariables.DEVELOPING)
            Log.v(TAG, url.toString());

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod(type);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(GlobalVariables.applyInternetConnectionTimeOut);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(GlobalVariables.applyInternetSocketTimeOut);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", oauth.getToken_type() + " " + oauth.getAccess_token());

        OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        os.write(jsonStr.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();

        return urlConnection;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have written this code in volley for same request

```
    StringRequest= new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                  // Successfull Stuff
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                  Log.d(TAG, "onErrorResponse: " + error.toString());

                }
            }
    ) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("allValue", jsonStr);
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            params.put("Accept", "application/json");
            params.put("Authorization", oauth.getToken_type() + " " + oauth.getAccess_token());
            return params;
        }
    };

    /*Generate Queue to line up apply request*/
    RequestQueue requestQueue =  VollySingleton.getsInstance().getmRequestQueue();
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

So My specific question is **where does that jsonStr go in Volley request** 
With String request It gives 400 error(Bad Request)
With JSonObject Request It gives 500 error

In Http URL Connection every thing is working fine and jsonStr is getting passed in

```
OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
          os.write(jsonStr.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();
```

Comment: If you are trying to get the `JSON` data from some server, use `JsonObjectRequest`. Next, the code you are using, that does not work with hardcoded JSON strings. Your code is trying to pull the JSON data  from the server through the URL you mention. Take a look at  this tutorial, and you'll get an idea how `volley` works. (http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-volley--cms-23800)

Comment: I read the document but never found anything about jsonStr with request, In HttpURLConnection their was Option of OutputStream where is that option or similar option in volley same I have asked in question.

Comment: `public void onResponse(String response){...}` - `response` is similar to your `jsonStr`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved the Issue
 Created Object of StringEntity Which is getting Used in event HttpClient Request

```
 StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(JsonStr);
```

and then Overrride method

```
 @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return entity.getContentType().getValue();
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() {
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            try {
                entity.writeTo(outputStream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                VolleyLog.e("IOException @ " + getClass().getSimpleName());
            }
            return outputStream.toByteArray();
        }
```

so the complete Answer will be

```
StringRequest= new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

              // Successfull Stuff
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

              Log.d(TAG, "onErrorResponse: " + error.toString());

            }
        }
) {

     @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return entity.getContentType().getValue();
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() {
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            try {
                entity.writeTo(outputStream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                VolleyLog.e("IOException @ " + getClass().getSimpleName());
            }
            return outputStream.toByteArray();
        }


    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        params.put("Accept", "application/json");
        params.put("Authorization", oauth.getToken_type() + " " + oauth.getAccess_token());
        return params;
    }
};

/*Generate Queue to line up apply request*/
RequestQueue requestQueue =  VollySingleton.getsInstance().getmRequestQueue();
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```